# Message sending from iPhone to another mobile

Tags: iphone, ios

In my app am using **MFMessageComposeViewController** to send message.
Following code is the example i used to send message

```
        MFMessageComposeViewController *msgController = [[[MFMessageComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
        if([MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText])
        {
            msgController.messageComposeDelegate = self;
            msgController.body = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", appDelegate.finalConactStr ];
            [self presentModalViewController:msgController animated:YES];
        }
```

and am checking the result by using the following code

```
- (void)messageComposeViewController:(MFMessageComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MessageComposeResult)result 
{
    switch (result)
    {
    case MessageComposeResultCancelled:
        cancelAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"SMS a Contact" message:@"Cancelled"delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [cancelAlert show];
        [cancelAlert release];
        NSLog(@"Result: canceled");
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultSent:
        successAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SMS a Contact" message:@"Successfully sent" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [successAlert show];
        [successAlert release];
        NSLog(@"Result: sent");
        break;
    case MessageComposeResultFailed:
        failAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SMS a Contact" message:@"Failed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [failAlert show];
        [failAlert release];

        NSLog(@"Result: failed");
        break;
    default:
        notSentAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"SMS a Contact" message:@"Not Sent" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [notSentAlert show];
        [notSentAlert release];

        NSLog(@"Result: not sent");
        break;
    }
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

but without sim also it is showing alert like **Successfully sent**

How can we check device has sim or not or message sending capability is there or not.
Any one can help or suggest me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Since Apple introduced iMessage all device that can run iOS5 will be able to send a message via [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Thus there is no real need to check wheter there is a sim installed in the device, just trust the [`[MFMessageComposeViewController canSendText]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009668-CH1-SW3) to tell you wether the device can send a message.

- `MessageComposeResultCancelled` : The user canceled the composition.
- `MessageComposeResultSent` : The user successfully queued or sent the message.
- `MessageComposeResultFailed` : The user’s attempt to save or send the message was unsuccessful.

Comment: but when i run on device it is always showing successfully sent.

Comment: Then the message is sent, why do you think is't not sent?

Comment: but without sim and also without number also showing successfully sent.

Comment: Since iMessage you can also send message to email addresses (Apple ID). If they fail there is nothing you can do about it, since you can't acces this from your code. Send a bug report to Apple.

Comment: @rckoenes: Check your definitions of constants you have made mistake. i think interchange description of constant.

Comment: If i have no balance in my sim, but i am getting success result MessageComposeResultSent..After that in sms app getting failed message notification...

Comment: @vikramarkaios this is known, since only later the network informs the phone the SMS is not send. Please submit this in a bug request to Apple.